# Integrate MorphOne field in form

Tags: octobercms

I have the following setup:

```
class Frontbox extends Model
{ ...
  public $morphTo = [ 
      'frontable'=>[] 
  ];
}

class Piece extends Model
{ ...
  public $morphOne = [
       'frontboxes'=>['Acme\Teasers\Models\Frontbox',name'=>'frontable'] 
  ];
}

//Form Field Definitions for piece:
fields:
    pagetitle:
        label: Title
    ...
    frontboxes:
        type: partial
        path: frontbox_partial

//Form Field Definitions for frontbox:
fields:
    title:
        label: Frontbox Title
    ...
```

Now I would like to handle the frontbox fields as if they were part of the piece model (i.e. create update and delete them automatically so that the user doesn't realize its not part of the Piece entity).
Obviously later I will have other Models that use the same frontboxes (similar to the piece model here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it in the code:
You can use the field just like a field of the Model when you set it in Parantheses and prepend it with the relation:

```
#=========================
fields.yaml:
#=========================
fields:
    id:
        label: ID
        disabled: true
    slug:
        label: Field Slug
    frontboxes[title]:
        label: Front Title
        type: text
    title:
        label: Piece Title
    ...
```